# ninja IRC client

Tags: linux, console, ncurses, irc

I'm having a problem when compiling ninja IRC client. (http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/gentoo/distfiles/5b/ninja-1.5.9pre14.tar.gz)

It compiles fine, but segfaults upon executing. When strace'ing the program, it says that it is using `/lib64/libtinfo.so.6`, but here's the problem, i'm using openSUSE Leap (version 15.4) and YaST uses that shared library. When I try compiling/installing a newer version of libtinfo (ncurses), it breaks YaST, to the point where it will not work. I had to `ln -s` the old version of `libtinfo`.

So, my question is this: Can I force ninja to use a different version of `libtinfo`?

I *was* using Debian Bullseye before, and I never came upon this problem...

Comment: Waah! Do not overwrite system-provided libraries with self-compiled ones! That *must*, by the logic of what an soversion is, break things. That's universally true for any operating system, not just Suse.

Comment: Why would your strace show you where the crash happens? It could only show you that the opening syscalls for that library have been made, but I bet that's true for a lot of other libraries as well, so how do you know this crash happens die to having loaded libtinfo?